# KVM - How to remove virtual video card, but keep the SPICE Server?

Tags: kvm, gpu, spice

I am passing through a physical GPU to my virtual machine, and using the SPICE Server/Display Spice for sound. However, the virtual GPU (Cirrus/QXL/VGA/Virtio/VMVGA/Xen) is causing some sort of conflict with the real GPU, as when it is enabled, the monitor which I am using to display the output from the real GPU displays none or incorrect output.

I have tried this with all the possible virtual video cards, and had the most success with VMVGA, which allowed me to go as far as displaying the GRUB menu. There was no output after actually booting up the OS (Debian Testing). With others, not even the GRUB was displayed.

If I remove both the SPICE Server and the video card, the real GPU works well with the correct output, drivers and everything. But as stated, I need the SPICE Server. I tried to remove only the virtual video card, both through virtmanager and XML modification, but it always returns.

Is there any way to remove the card, but keep SPICE?

Is there any other way to make the virtual sound device work (it doesn't seem to work without SPICE, specifically it doesn't play the sound on the host)?

If the card cannot be removed, can it be disabled, so the virtual machine/guest OS won't touch it at all?

Any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

SPICE is the video, it's a protocol that includes video, sound and control channels for remote access to the qemu process controlling the guest. You can't decouple the sound from the server. If you need to use a passed through video card, you might as well pass the sound card through too.